# ERROR ITMS-90032: Invalid Image Path

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am deploying my Xamarin forms iOS application in App Store. While deploying I am getting errors as follows.

This is the error I am getting:

> /var/folders/q_/18cndwcd5zz7ky11gp4v0nv80000gn/T/C24E9DA1-0526-4D75-A483-7B87CC3D050E/1276990237.itmsp - Error Messages:
>           ERROR ITMS-90032: “Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key ‘CFBundleIconFiles’: ‘Icon’”
>           ERROR ITMS-90032: “Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key ‘CFBundleIconFiles’: ‘Icon@2x’”
>           ERROR ITMS-90032: “Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key ‘CFBundleIconFiles’: ‘Icon-60@2x’”
>           ERROR ITMS-90032: “Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key ‘CFBundleIconFiles’: ‘Icon-72’”
>           ERROR ITMS-90032: “Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key ‘CFBundleIconFiles’: ‘Icon-72@2x’”
>           ERROR ITMS-90032: “Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key ‘CFBundleIconFiles’: ‘Icon-76’”
>           ERROR ITMS-90032: “Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key ‘CFBundleIconFiles’: ‘Icon-76@2x’”
>           ERROR ITMS-90032: “Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key ‘CFBundleIconFiles’: ‘Icon-Small’”
>           ERROR ITMS-90032: “Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key ‘CFBundleIconFiles’: ‘Icon-Small@2x’”
>           ERROR ITMS-90032: “Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key ‘CFBundleIconFiles’: ‘Icon-Small-50’”
>           ERROR ITMS-90032: “Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key ‘CFBundleIconFiles’: ‘Icon-Small-50@2x’”
>           ERROR ITMS-90032: “Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key ‘CFBundleIconFiles’: ‘Icon-Small-40’”
>           ERROR ITMS-90032: “Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key ‘CFBundleIconFiles’: ‘Icon-Small-40@2x’”

I didn't named these images as above and some of the images are not in my application. How to resolve the issue?

I am deploying this application using my Mac.

Comment: In your solution, within your iOS project theres an item called 'Asset Catalogs' double click on this, and take a look at what's inside. You need icon assets before you can submit to apple.

Comment: Thanks for your response.yeah there are icons but the images which are are shown in the error are not a part of the project

Comment: In that case, open up your project file in notepad, or any word editor, and then find the references to the above images, and just delete them, save and reopen your solution, try again, and you should find that it works.

Comment: yeah but i am not able to get the references.Could u please tell me a way to delete the CFBundle icon files once

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, I opened `info.plist` and chose the `Source`-tab. Then just removed the whole `Bundle icon files`-key since all the contained image references gave warning. Alternatively, I guess you could remove the subkeys giving warning.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

(after wasting quite a bit of time chasing wrong leads...) Make sure, especially if you are importing a iconset generated from the likes of, say, https://www.fanstudio.co.uk/appicon/, that you **DONT put the Assets.xcassets in a Xamarin subfolder** (eg under /Resources/) because the pathnames in the associated (generated) Contents.json catalog file wont match. If you do so by mistake then the icons dont get picked up by Application Loader when you attempt to upload your app, resulting in errors about required icons that otherwise appear to be perfectly present in your source tree!